# Jquery validate always true in a login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to implement a simple login form with spring security. But I want to ensure that every time the user push the button the form is only submited after everything is filled.

I'm using to validate the Jquery validate and the problem is after pushing the button the form is submited anyways (even if all fields are empty).

My JSP is:

```
<form id="loginuser" name="loginuser" action="<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" htmlEscape="true" />" method="POST"  class="login">  
    <div id="user_login">
        <fieldset>
            <dl>
                <input type='text' name='other_email' id='other_email'> 
                <dt><label for="j_username"><fmt:message key="app.username" />:</label></dt>
                <dd><input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" value="" tabindex="1" required/></dd>
                <dt><label for="j_password"><fmt:message key="app.password" />:</label></dt>
                <dd><input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" tabindex="2" required/></dd>               
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
        <p class="btn-paragraph">   
            <input type="submit" class="submitLoginButton btn-submit-style" value="<fmt:message key="app.login"/>" />

            <% // TODO: Quando a pagina de recovery password estiver concluida alterar o link para la!!  %>
            <a href="www.google.pt" class="help-link"><fmt:message key="login.recovery" /></a>
        </p> 
        <div id="loading" style="display:none;">
            <img id="loading-image" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/loader.gif"/>" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my Javascript code is:

```
$(function() {

    $('#loginuser').validate({
        errorClass: 'errors',
        validClass: 'successes',
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {            
            j_username: {
                minlength: minLength,
                loginUsernameRegex: true,
                required: true
            },
            j_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: minLength
            }
        },
        messages: {
            j_username: {
                    minlength: '<fmt:message key="registeruser.username.minlength"/>',
                    required: '<fmt:message key="registeruser.username.required"/>',
                    loginUsernameRegex: '<fmt:message key="registeruser.username.alfanumeric.only"/>'
                }, 
            j_password:  {
                minlength: '<fmt:message key="registeruser.pwd.minlength"/>',
                required: '<fmt:message key="registeruser.pwd.required"/>'
            }
        },

        showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();
        return false;
        }
    });

    $('.submitLoginButton').click(function(evt){
        if($('#other_email').val() && $('#other_email').val().length > 0){
            return false;
        }

        if($('#loginuser').valid()){
            console.log("Valid form");
        }
        else{console.log("not valid");}

        return false;
    });
});
```

So everytime my console show the "Valid form" message. Someone knows what I'm missing here??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/576y7/), and it appears to work.

I think, however, you should register an on-submit handler for the form, rather than an on-click handler for the button.

```
$('#loginuser').submit(function() {
    if ($('#other_email').val()) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/576y7/1/)

Comment: stupid me!! After struggling with this I found the error. I had another form with the same Id hided inside a div in my header file!! Thank you about all the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

try setting up an if statement that checks whether or not the field is empty. `if j_username == nil{do something};` Good luck! :D